# Replace part of a string with single word from the same string

Tags: python, regex, csv

Here is the output of my code:

```
Tue Dec 17 04:34:03 +0000 2013,Email me for tickets email me at stormyjackson28@Gmail.com,1708824644
Tue Dec 17 04:33:58 +0000 2013,@musclepotential ok man. you can email sbrown9049@gmail.com,25016561
```

I want to find the email address in the `,<text>,` (the text between the commas) and then reprint just the email.

Example:

```
Tue Dec 17 04:34:03 +0000 2013, stormyjackson28@Gmail.com,1708824644
Tue Dec 17 04:33:58 +0000 2013, brown9049@gmail.com,25016561
```

I know I can use the regex below to get just the email but then I loose the other data.

```
string = str(messages)
regex = "\w+@\w+\.com"
match = re.findall(regex,string)
```

Comment: What does the input look like?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `\w+` isn't good enough.  what about `joe.smith@gmail.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers above rely on your text being remarkably similar to your examples. This code is a little more agile, matching any number of emails in your text. I did not thoroughly document it, but...

harvest_emails takes a string of line-separated strings, each of those comma-separated as in your examples, `date`,`message_string`,`identifier`, and returns a generator that produces a 3-length tuple `(date,comma-sep-emails,identifier)`. It will pull any number of emails from the text and matches any email of the form `x@x.com | x@x.net | x@x.org` where x is any non-zero length series of non-whitespace characters.

```
def harvest_emails(target):
    """"Takes string, splits it on \n, then yields each line formatted as:
datecode, email, identifier
"""
    import re

    for line in target.splitlines():
        t = line.split(",")
        yield (
            t[0].strip(),
            ','.join(
                re.findall("\S+@\S+\.(?:com|org|net)",
                           ''.join(t[1:-1]).strip(),re.I)[0:]),
            t[-1].strip())
```

.

```
>>>messages = """04:34:03 +0000 2013,Email me for tickets email me at stormyjackson28@Gmail.com,1708824644
Tue Dec 17 04:33:58 +0000 2013,@musclepotential ok, man. you can email sbrown9049@gmail.com,25016561
Tue Dec 17 04:34:03 +0000 2013, stormyjackson28@Gmail.Com, name@domain.com,1708824644
Tue Dec 17 04:33:58 +0000 2013, brown9049@gmail.com,25016561"""
>>>data = list()
>>>for line in harvest_emails(messages):
        d = dict()
        d["date"],d["emails"],d["id"] = line[0],line[1].split(','),line[2]
        data.append(d)
>>>for value in data:
        print(value)
{'emails': ['stormyjackson28@Gmail.com'], 'date': '04:34:03 +0000 2013', 'id': '1708824644'}
{'emails': ['sbrown9049@gmail.com'], 'date': 'Tue Dec 17 04:33:58 +0000 2013', 'id': '25016561'}
{'emails': ['stormyjackson28@Gmail.Com', 'name@domain.com'], 'date': 'Tue Dec 17 04:34:03 +0000 2013', 'id': '1708824644'}
{'emails': ['brown9049@gmail.com'], 'date': 'Tue Dec 17 04:33:58 +0000 2013', 'id': '25016561'}
```

Answer (score 2):

based on your examples
use this pattern `,.*?(\S+),` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lI8hV7)
this solution is independent of the email pattern as it is one of the most sought patterns
and it could vary a lot such as first.last@us.gov

Comment: Note that this only works if the email address is between commas, and it captures the last word of ANYTHING between commas.

Answer (score 1):

After your current code, try this:

```
new_string = string.split(',')
new_string[1] = match[0]
output_string = ', '.join(new_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work well...

```
string = str(messages)
regex = "(?<=,).*?(?=\S+,\d+$)"
ouput_str=re.sub(regex,"",string)
```